# Generate dynamic input fields based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a form that should have a selection to select no of Member. Based on number the user select number of table row generated for input. 
At this moment i have the following one.. which has selection ....but max four row field is defined. User only select the no of member and then fill the form. 
I want that user at first select no of member. for example user selects 2 ...then 2 row will generate to fill up .

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        No Of Members: <select name="member" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="0">Select</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>


       </select>
    </label>
  </div>

 <div>           
          <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email </th>
                        <th>CGPA</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA" required></td>
                    <tr/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA"></td>
                    <tr/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA"></td>
                    <tr/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA"></td>
                    <tr/>


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I have found similar solution in JSFiddle [ http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/H3z5P/ ] . 
But it has a problem ....every time i input a number ....it adds that number of rows with previous. and it has not selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the key code from your Fiddle in your question.

If I understand what you are wanting, it seems that you need to add or subtract rows depending on the size of the table and the requested number of rows. So you can test the current number and adjust as in the following:

```
$('[name="cand_no"]').on('change', function() {
  // Not checking for Invalid input
  if (this.value != '') {
    var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    var rows = $('#studentTable tr'),
        rowCnt = rows.length - 1; // Allow for header row

    if (rowCnt > val) {
        for (var i = rowCnt; i > val; i--) {
            rows[i].remove();
        }
    }
    if (rowCnt < val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < val - rowCnt; i++) {
            // Clone the Template
            var $cloned = $('.template tbody').clone();
            // For each Candidate append the template row
            $('#studentTable tbody').append($cloned.html());
        }
    }
  }
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/nev53fur/)

Comment: yes...just like this....but only need the selection instead of input in the No of Candidates

Comment: Change this $('[name="cand_no"]') into $('select [name="member"]')